# Can I show the comments posted on my website, with fb comment plugin, in my facebook app page?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I saw this question here: [How do I link Facebooks comments box to a specific facebook page or application](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4504584/how-do-i-link-facebooks-comments-box-to-a-specific-facebook-page-or-application)

But it was from 2010, I was thinking it could be a new way to do this.

Basically show the comments and likes (if it is possible) from my website on the facebook app page

Thanks

Laura

Comment: Nope, the answer to question you refer too is still correct and nothing changed.

Comment: what a pity! thanks for the answer!